# How to show an icon in the middle of the screen for an empty listview?

Tags: android, listview

As you can see the picture below that when there is no item in the list it shows nice icon in the middle of the screen with a text. I can get only a text shown if the listview is empty with this code in my custom layout :

```
  <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#FF0000"
           android:text="No data"/>
```

adding this element in my layout show a text when the list is empty. I would like to show an icon instead and also it should be in the middle of the screen. Instead of a textview if I use a imageView again it goes top of the screen. what is the best approach to this? I might be able to get it as I like using imageview and textview and both with `android:id="@android:id/empty` attribute. or is that possbile to have layout with the `android:id="@android:id/empty` attribute and place imageview and textview inside?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use a layout. LinearLayout might work well in this case. You'll probably have to set the gravity to center. It seems you already had the right idea, I'm not sure why you didn't just try it out? You would have had it!

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that this is the best approach. Sometimes you can get things worked but might be a better way of doing this which I dont know:) Thank you. I did it :)